# __setitem__() implementation in Python for Point(x,y) class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a Point class in python. I already have some of the functions, like __ str__ , or __ getitem__ implemented, and it works great.
The only problem I'm facing is that my implementation of the __ setitem__ does not work, the others are doing fine.

Here is my Point class, and the last function is my `__ setitem__()`:

```
class point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "point(%s,%s)" % (self.x, self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return (self.x, self.y)[item]

    def __setitem__(self, x, y):
        [self.x, self.y][x] = y
```

It should work like this:

```
p = point(2, 3)
p[0] = 1  # sets the x coordinate to 1
p[1] = 10  # sets the y coordinate to 10
```

Am I even right, should the `**setitem**()  work like this?
Thanks!

Comment: should it not be self.data.x ?

Comment: Have you tried it? What does it do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let `self.data` and only `self.data` hold the coordinate values. 
If `self.x` and `self.y` were to also store these values there is a chance `self.data` and `self.x` or `self.y` will not get updated consistently.

Instead, make `x` and `y` [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) that look up their values from `self.data`.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.data=[x, y]

    def __str__(self):
        return "point(%s,%s)"%(self.x,self.y)

    def __getitem__(self,item):
        return self.data[item]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        self.data[idx] = value

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.data[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.data[1]
```

---

The statement

```
[self.x, self.y][x]=y
```

is interesting but problematic. Let pick it apart:

`[self.x, self.y]` causes Python to build a **new list**, with values `self.x` and `self.y`.

`somelist[x]=y` causes Python to assign value `y` to the `x`th index of `somelist`. So this new list `somelist` gets updated. But this has no effect on `self.data`, `self.x` or `self.y`. That is why your original code was not working.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty old post, but the solution for your problem is very simple:

```
class point(object):
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def __str__(self):
        return "point(%s,%s)"%(self.x,self.y)

    def __getitem__(self,item):
        return self.__dict__[item]

    def __setitem__(self,item,value):
        self.__dict__[item] = value
```

Each class has his own dictionary with all properties and methods created inside the class. So with this you can call:

```
In [26]: p=point(1,1)
In [27]: print p
point(1,1)
In [28]: p['x']=2
In [29]: print p
point(2,1)
In [30]: p['y']=5
In [31]: print p
point(2,5)
```

It is more readable then your "index" like reference.

Answer (score 2):

Let's strip this down to the bare minimum:

```
x, y = 2, 3
[x, y][0] = 1
print(x)
```

This will print out `2`.

Why?

Well, `[x, y]` is a brand-new list containing two elements. When you do reassign its first member to `1`, that just changes the brand-new list, so its first element is now `1` instead of `2`. It doesn't turn the number `2` into the number `1`.

Since your code is essentially identical to this, it has the same problem. As long as your variables have immutable values, you can't mutate the variables.

---

You *could* fix it by doing something like this:

```
x, y = [2], [3]
[x, y][0][0] = 1
print(x[0])
```

Now you'll get `1`.

Why? Well, `[x, y]` is a new list with two elements, each of which is a list. You're not replacing its first element with something else, you're replacing the first element of its first element with something else. But its first element is the same list as `x`, so you're also replacing `x`'s first element with something else.

---

If this is a bit hard to keep straight in your head… well, that's usually a sign that you're doing something you probably shouldn't be. (Also, the fact that you're using `x` for a parameter that means "select `x` or `y`" and `y` for a parameter that means "new value" makes it a whole lot more confusing…)

There are many simpler ways to do the same thing:

- Use an `if`/`else` statement instead of trying to get fancy.
- Use a single `list` instead of two integer values: `self.values[x] = y`. (That's unutbu's answer.)
- Use a `dict` instead of two integer values: `self.values['xy'[x]] = y`.
- Use `setattr(self, 'xy'[x], y)`.
- Use a `namedtuple` instead of trying to build the same thing yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This works in python 2.6 i guess it works for 2.7 as well

The **__*setitem*__** method accept 3 arguments (self, index, value)

in this case we want to use index as int for retrive the name of the coordinate from **__*slots*__** tuple (check the documentation of **__*slots*__** is really usefull for performance)

remember with **__*slots*__** only **x** and **y** attributes are allowed! so:

```
p = Point()
p.x = 2
print(p.x)  # 2.0

p.z = 4  # AttributeError
print(p.z)  # AttributeError
```

This way is faster respect using **@property** decorator (when you start to have 10000+ instances)

```
class Point(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._data[0]  # where self._data = [x, y]
...
```

so this is my tip for you :)

```
class Point(object):

    __slots__ = ('x', 'y')  # Coordinates

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        '''
        You can use the constructor in many ways:
        Point() - void arguments
        Point(0, 1) - passing two arguments
        Point(x=0, y=1) - passing keywords arguments
        Point(**{'x': 0, 'y': 1}) - unpacking a dictionary
        Point(*[0, 1]) - unpacking a list or a tuple (or a generic iterable)
        Point(*Point(0, 1)) - copy constructor (unpack the point itself)
        '''
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        object.__setattr__(self, attr, float(value))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
            '''
            p = Point()
            p[0]  # is the same as self.x
            p[1]  # is the same as self.y
            '''
        return self.__getattribute__(self.__slots__[index])

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
            '''
            p = Point()
            p[0] = 1
            p[1] = -1
            print(repr(p))  # <Point (1.000000, -1.000000)>
            '''
        self.__setattr__(self.__slots__[index], value)  # converted to float automatically by __setattr__

    def __len__(self):
        '''
        p = Point()
        print(len(p))  # 2
        '''
        return 2

    def __iter__(self):
        '''
        allow you to iterate
        p = Point()
        for coord in p:
            print(coord)

        for i in range(len(p)):
            print(p[i])
        '''
        return iter([self.x, self.y])

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%f, %f)" % (self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Point %s>" % self
```

Answer (score 1):

Your may find it a lot easier to use namedtuple for this:

```
 from collections import namedtuple
 Point= namedtuple('Point', ['x','y'])

 fred = Point (1.0, -1.0)
 #Result: Point(x=1.0, y=-1.0)
```

The main drawback is that you can't poke values into a namedtuple - it's immutable. In most applications that's a feature, not a bug

Answer (score 0):

What's happening in setitem is it builds a temporary list, sets the value, then throws away this list without changing self.x or self.y. Try this for `__setitem__`:

```
def __setitem__(self,coord,val):
    if coord == 0:
        self.x = val
    else:
        self.y = val
```

This is quite an abuse of `__setitem__`, however... I'd advise figuring out a different way of setting the x/y coordinates if possible. Using p.x and p.y is going to be much faster than p[0] and p[1] pretty much no matter how you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Deck = namedtuple('cards',['suits','values'])

class FrenchDeck(object):

    deck = [str(i) for i in range(2,11)]+list('JQKA')
    suits = "heart clubs spades diamond".split()

    def __init__(self):
        self.totaldecks = [Deck(each,every) for each in self.suits for every in self.deck]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.totaldecks)
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.totaldecks[index]
    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        self.totaldecks[key] = value

CardDeck = FrenchDeck()
CardDeck[0] = "asdd"       # needs`__setitem__()`
print CardDeck[0]
```

If you don't use the `__setitem__()`,  you will get an error

```
TypeError: 'FrenchDeck' object does not support item assignment
```