# How to implement 2D access with double brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my own class I'd like to support 2D access with double brackets. So with `game` being an instance of the class, I want to support:

- Getting a value with `game[line][col]`.
- Setting a value with `game[line][col] = val`.

The internal attribute actually holding the data is a one-dimensional list (representing a 2D board):

```
class Board:
    self.board = [0] * size**2 #attribute to access
```

The get item one was easy (even if I'm open to improvements)

```
def __getitem__(self, line):
    assert line >= 0
    ret = []
    for l in range(line * self.size, (line + 1) * self.size):
        ret.append(self.board[l])
    return ret
```

This, as you might know, allows me to do :

```
game = Board(12) # 12 times 12 board
print(game[1][6])
```

But I don't see how to do the set item one. I have this method that does the same but no way to translate it in an operator way.

```
def setVal(self, line, col, val):
    assert line >= 0 and col >= 0
    self.board[line * self.size + col] = val
```

Comment: `[0]` is a list object, not an operator

Comment: yes, I know :) is the object that I want to modify

Comment: I don't think you can override object types

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_setitem\_\_ implementation in Python for Point(x,y) class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774804/setitem-implementation-in-python-for-pointx-y-class)

Comment: well, it works for the getter I suppose, that there is surely an answer for the setter.

Comment: What my class has is a list called board. this board represent in fact a matrix which means there are 2 coordinates to access an element.

Comment: You could consider using `board[i,j]` instead of `board[i][j]`. That would make the implementation much easier.

Comment: @Heike you are right, I already did it like that for now. But is not consistent and I really would like to know how to do it well.

Comment: Btw, `line and col >= 0` doesn't do what you think it does. Try calling `game.setVal(0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @cricket_007 That's not what was meant, see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your desired `game[2][3] = 42` does is it calls `game.__getitem__(2).__setitem__(3, 42)`. So you could make your `__getitem__` return an object with a `__setitem__` method that writes into the board (and a `__getitem__` method that reads from it).

Code with demo:

```
class Board:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.board = [0] * size**2

    def __getitem__(self, line):
        board = self.board
        size = self.size
        class Line:
            def __getitem__(self, col):
                return board[line * size + col]
            def __setitem__(self, col, val):
                board[line * size + col] = val
        return Line()

game = Board(4)
print('before:', game[2][3])
game[2][3] = 42
print('after:', game[2][3])
print('peek:', game.board)
```

Output:

```
before: 0
after: 42
peek: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```