# Python 3: Setting new value for an attribute given inside a list

Tags: python

I'm sorry for the confusing title. I am not entirely sure how to define my problem.

So, I would like to make a vector class where it is possible to assign the x- and y-attributes by using vec[item] = value.
Since I have trouble explaining it, this is basically what I want:

```
vec = Vec(1,3)
vec[0] = 2
print(f'x-coordinate is: {vec.x}')
```

I would like this statement to print: `x-coordinate is: 2`. As of now it prints `x-coordinate is: 1`

How do I implement this properly in my Vec class?

---

This is part of the Vec class. I'm trying to use `__setitem__()`

```
class Vec():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x; self.y = y
        self.lis = [self.x,self.y]
        self.dic  = {'x' : self.x, 'y': self.y}

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, int):
            return self.lis[item]
        if isinstance(item, str):
            return self.dic[item]

# What I've tried
    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        if isinstance(item, int):
            self.lis.__setitem__(item, value)       #<--?
            self.lis[item] = value                  #<--?
        if isinstance(item, str):
            return self.dic.__setitem__(item, value)
```

I hope my problem is understandable.
(I apologize for my naming of things - It is not my strong suit)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_setitem\_\_ implementation in Python for Point(x,y) class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774804/setitem-implementation-in-python-for-pointx-y-class)

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        if isinstance(item, int):
            if item == 0:
                self.x = value
            elif item== 1:
                self.y = value
```

Primitive types are copied by value, not by reference.